# Optimizing regex for sentence sanitizer

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is a sentence sanitizer.

```
function sanitize_sentence($string) {
    $pats = array(
    '/([.!?]\s{2}),/',      # Abc.  ,Def
    '/\.+(,)/',             # ......,
    '/(!|\?)\1+/',          # abc!!!!!!!!, abc?????????
    '/\s+(,)/',             # abc   , def
    '/([a-zA-Z])\1\1/');    # greeeeeeen
    $fixed = preg_replace($pats,'$1',$string); # apply pats
    $fixed = preg_replace('/(?:(?<=\s)|^)[^a-z0-9]+(?:(?=\s)|$)/i', '',$fixed); # bad chunks
    $fixed = preg_replace( '/([!?,.])(\S)/', '$1 $2', $fixed); # spaces after punctuation, if it doesn't exist already
    $fixed = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9!?.]+$/', '.', $fixed); # end of string must end in period
    $fixed = preg_replace('/,(?!\s)/',', ',$fixed); # spaces after commas
    return $fixed;
}
```

This is the test sentence:

> hello [[[[[[]]]]]] friend.....?       how are you [}}}}}}

It should return:

> hello friend.....? how are you

But instead it is returning:

> hello friend. .. .. ? how are you.

So there are 2 problems and I can't find a solution around them:

1. the set of periods are being separated into ".. .. ." for some reason. They should remain as "....." next to the question mark.
2. the end of the string must end in a period only *and only* if there is at least one of these characters anywhere in the string: **!?,.** (if at least one of those characters are not found in the string, that preg_replace should not be executed)

Examples for the second problem:

> This sentence doesn't need an ending period because the mentioned characters are nowhere to be found
>
> This other sentence, needs it! Why? Because it contains at least one of the mentioned characters

*(of course, the ending period should only be placed if it doesn't exist yet)*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: English grammar validation via regex is never going to end well.

Comment: If you can't parse (X)HTML via regular expression, **how do you want to parse spoken languages**? They're somewhat more irregular than some XML markup.

Comment: when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail...

Comment: I have a pair of rubber gloves so everything looks like a ....

Comment: It is not like the OP is really trying sanitize "spoken language". I believe some validation of punctuation can certainly be a regular problem.

Comment: exactly, this has nothing to do with grammar validation. it is just merely punctuation structure.

Comment: @andufo I don't really get your second problem. firstly, the result you get matches your condition (it contains `.` and `?`, hence it ends in a period). Secondly your second-to-last pattern will always append a period if there is at least one non-word, non-punctuation at the end. So what **do** you actually want to accomplish with that step?

Comment: @m.buettner i added an example at the end of the post to be more clear on the second problem.

Comment: @andufo still. why should the period be missing from your first example? it contains `.` and `?`

Comment: "it is just merely punctuation structure" punctuation is part of grammar

Comment: @m.buettner the first example should insert the period, because there is a question mark and other periods inside the string. In the second example set, only the 2nd sentence needs it, because the 1st one doesn't have any of the special characters inside.

Comment: @Dagon this is still not trying to automatically correct punctuation (in a grammatical sense) but just some basic correction with respect to the relative positions of punctuation and non-punctuation characters. also instead of saying, "you can't use regex for that"... how about presenting an alternative?

Comment: @andufo okay, so that means your first example is wrong, because you explicitly state that you expect the period **not** to be there.

Comment: @m.buettner not quite, i clarify that the period should be added only and only if there is at least one of these characters anywhere in the string: !?,. (and of course if it hasn't been placed by the user). The  1st example is for the first problem, the second example was added to better understand the second problem.

Comment: @m.buettner actually, the 'adding-period-regex' works fine. The current issue is that it should only be applied if at least one instance of the ,.?! characters are found inside the string.

Comment: @andufo I updated my answer. I still think that your first example should reflect both conditions and not state that you **expect to end without a `.`** if your second condition actually requires one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer to your first problem. The third-to-last replacement is the problem:

```
$fixed = preg_replace( '/([!?,.])(\S)/', '$1 $2', $fixed); # spaces after punctuation, if it doesn't exist already
```

It will match the first period with the character class, and the second period as a non-space character. Then insert a space. Since matches cannot overlap, it will then match the third and forth period and insert a space and so on. This is probably best fixed like this:

```
$fixed = preg_replace( '/[!?,.](?![!?,.\s])/', '$0 ', $fixed);
```

Here is how you could go about your second requirement (replace the second-to-last `preg_replace`):

```
$fixed = trim($fixed);
$fixed = preg_replace( '/[!?.,].*(?<![.!?])$/', '$0.', $fixed);
```

First we get rid of leading and trailing whitespace to separate this concern from the trailing period. Then the `preg_replace` will try to find a punctuation character in the string and if it does, it matches everything until the end of the string. The replacement puts the match back in place and appends the period. Note the negative lookbehind. It asserts that the string does not already end with a sentence-ending punctuation character.

Comment: i was testing your addition, it works great except on the last hack, hehe. Would it be posible to keep the original last character in case it is a **!** or **?** instead of replacing it with a period?

Comment: @andufo sure, using `trim` separately is probably a better approach anyway. see my edit